# How convert OffsetDateTime with open csv 5.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, opencsv

I am using open csv 5.0

to be able to read the data imported from a csv file

I am facing a problem regarding

the conversion of a DateOffsetDateTime format.

here my code :

the model :

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IndProdCsv {

    @CsvBindByName
    private Long id;
    @CsvBindByName
    private String service;
    @CsvBindByName
    private OffsetDateTime time;
    @CsvBindByName
    private Long nbAppels;
    @CsvBindByName
    private Double tempsDeReponseMoyenMillisecondes;
    @CsvBindByName
    private Long volume;
    @CsvBindByName
    private Double tempsDeReponseMoyenSecondes;
}
```

controller :

```
  @PostMapping("/upload-csv-file")
    public String uplaodCSVFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model){
        if (file.isEmpty()){
            model.addAttribute("message", "Veuillez selectionner un fichier csv à importer.");
            model.addAttribute("status", false);
        }else try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {

            // create csv bean reader
            CsvToBean<IndProdCsv> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                    .withType(IndProdCsv.class)
                    .withSeparator(';')
                    .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                    .build();

            // convert `CsvToBean` object
            List<IndProdCsv> myIndProdCsv = csvToBean.parse();
            model.addAttribute("myIndProdCsv", myIndProdCsv);
            model.addAttribute("status", true);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "An error occurred while processing the CSV file.");
            model.addAttribute("status", false);
            }
        return "mon-dasboard";
    }
```

html with thymeleaf :

tr th:each="ind, i : ${myIndProdCsv}"

td th:text="${ind.time}"></td

/tr

and here is the error :

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Can't convert value '2020-09-18T00:50:00+02:00' to type class java.time.OffsetDateTime
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.conversionException(AbstractConverter.java:474)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.StringConverter.convertToType(StringConverter.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.convert(AbstractConverter.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ConverterFacade.convert(ConverterFacade.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:491)
    at com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.convertToRead(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:118)
    ... 9 more
```

thank you for your help